# group by and count with sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by

I have a sqlite table in my android app and I need to count how many items have the same date. Here is a simple schema of the table:

col1 | col2 | date_item |

xx   | xx   | 2012-04-12|

yy   | er   | 2012-05-12|

...    ...    ...

I suppose that to count how many row has the same date i need to do the query using group by. The problemm is that if I do as follow:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("table_name", new String[] {"date_item"}, null, null, "date_item", null, null);
```

and i return `cursor.getColumnCount();`. I get only 1 column. So how can i do this to have 2 columns (one for **date_item** and one for **count**)?

Thanks, Mattia

Comment: Solved, i edit the query function adding count(*) to the list of params:

    Cursor cursor = db.query("chiamate", new String[] {"data_intervento", "count(*)"}, null, null, "data_intervento", null, null);